# Teaming two NIC: iperf shows 200MB/s downloads but only 100MB/s upload

Tags: networking, centos, bonding, iperf

I have:

- One client with two 1000Mbps NICs, teamed using round-robin method
- One master with a 10Gbps NIC

They are connected with a Huawei 10G switch (S5700).

Then I ran `iperf -s` on master and `iperf -c MASTER.IP`, it reports bandwidth of `215MB/s`, as I expected.

But when I tried `iperf -s` on client and `iperf -c CLIENT.IP` on master, it reports bandwidth of only `120MB/s`, seems like only one network interface is used.

Both machine is running CentOS 7 and here's my teaming configuration:

ifcfg-team0:

```
DEVICE="team0"
DEVICETYPE="Team"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="none"
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.42.1
TEAM_CONFIG='{"runner": {"name": "roundrobin"}}'
```

ifcfg-enp2s0f0:

```
DEVICE="enp2s0f0"
DEVICETYPE="TeamPort"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="none"
TEAM_MASTER="team0"
```

(and also `ifcfg-enp2s0f1` which is almost identical to `ifcfg-enp2s0f0`)

---

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of the bonded system:

- Transmit goes out two slaves
- Receive comes in one slave

Even though it's TCP and is likely very out-of-order because of the round-robin bond, your transmit achieves about 1.8Gbps over two 1Gbps interfaces.

However, the switch does not have any configuration to load balance back into the system, so you are limited to the speed of one slave coming back the other way.